# Put and remove laptop battry while working

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

When I work on my laptop I remove the battery and work on AC power, but some times I want to move the the lap while its on I was think of putting the battery then remove the AC power, and when come back put the AC power and remove the battery all without turning off laptop.

I know this is duplicated but the answers is vary, My lab is lenovo g560. Is it ok to remove and put the battery without turning it off, hope to get the answer from someone who had lenovo laptop and done this trick alot.

And if anyone with any lap model had any issues doing this in his lap hope u can share what happen with us.

Comment: I know the question is duplicated but want hurt if leaved for couple of hours without closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [User Manual](http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/UserGuide/en/User's%20guides%20and%20manuals/G460-G560/G460&G560%20UserGuide%20V1.0%20EN%20147002899-1.1%20(10.03.18)_web.pdf) says

> Before removing the battery pack, make sure the computer has been shut down.

and

> You are advised to insert the battery pack when using your computer to prevent small particles from entering the inside of your computer.

Comment: "You are advised to insert the battery pack when using your computer to prevent small particles from entering the inside of your computer" what that mean, isn't better to remove the battery when plug the AC power?

Comment: @user195971: To my understanding, it only means that the battery forms part of the external enclosure or case and so, when the battery is removed, there is a large opening in the case into which dirt can get. On most laptops it is only the battery contacts (which nowadays include data contacts) that are exposed. Laptops are designed to be used with the battery in place, even when connected to external AC power. (Mine work with battery removed)